# Python TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am providing two values (mon_voltage and core_voltage) through command line, and I need to search a 'start point' from a two dimensional array from where my iteration or loop will start.

Here is my code:

```
myArray =  [[1.02,1.13],[1.02,1.16],[1.02,1.18],[1.02,1.21],[1.02,1.265]]

start_point = myArray.index([mon_voltage, core_voltage])
print "Start point is", start_point

for idx in enumerate(myArray):

     mon_voltage = myArray[idx + start_point][0]
     core_voltage = myArray[idx + start_point][1]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
  TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

I am unable to figure out why start_point, which is an index, is a tuple. Please help.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your valuable inputs !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) will return a `(index, value)` tuple.

You can access the index value as

```
idx[0]
```

**Example**

```
for idx in enumerate(myArray):    
       mon_voltage = myArray[idx[0] + start_point][0]
       core_voltage = myArray[idx[0] + start_point][1]
```

**OR**

```
for (idx, value) in enumerate(myArray):    
           mon_voltage = myArray[idx + start_point][0]
           core_voltage = myArray[idx + start_point][1]
```

Here the tuple is unpacked to `idx` and `value` and we use the `idx` for following logic what so ever may occur within the `for` loop.

The `value` will contain the value at index position `idx` that is `myArray[idx]`

Answer (score 1):

The `tuple` is `idx`, not `start_point`. This line:

```
for idx in enumerate(myArray):
```

Assigns a tuple object to `idx`. The `enumerate` function produces a tuple of the form:

```
(index_number, value)
```

What you probably want to do is just:

```
for idx, value in enumerate(myArray):
```

And ignore the `value` part.

Answer (score 1):

`idx` is a tuple, while `start_point` isn't

Builtin function [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns an iterator whose `next` will return tuples containing a count and a value obtained from sequence

In your case following tuples are returned

```
In [5]: list(enumerate(myArray))
Out[5]:
[(0, [1.02, 1.13]),
 (1, [1.02, 1.16]),
 (2, [1.02, 1.18]),
 (3, [1.02, 1.21]),
 (4, [1.02, 1.265])]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Start_point` is not a tuple; `idx` is. If you `print(idx)`, you'll see the output of the `enumerate()` method:

```
(0, [1.02, 1.13])
(1, [1.02, 1.16])
(2, [1.02, 1.18])
(3, [1.02, 1.21])
(4, [1.02, 1.265])
```

These are all tuples, consisting of an index and value.

Answer (score 0):

idx is indeed a tuple since `enumerate()` return a tuple.
If you want to extract the real index then try `idx[0]`.